# DOM menu with internal links - issue with syntax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax

I'm trying to get this small project finished for my DOM class (beginners).  I think my syntax is off.  Basically, we are to create a 1 page site with internal navigation.  Upon clicking the menu items, the other content is hidden, and only the content which is clicked is shown.  Simple, but I can't seem to get my the syntax to work with the IDs.

Here's what I have.  Thanks!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#cats').click(function(){
  $('#content1').show(200);
  $('#content2','#content3','#content4').hide('fast'); 
 
 });
 $('#food').click(function(){
  $('#content2').show(200);
  $('#content1','#content3','#content4').hide('fast'); 
 
 });
 $('#fashion').click(function(){
  $('#content3').show(200);
  $('#content1','#content2','#content4').hide('fast'); 
 
 });
 $('#animals').click(function(){
  $('#content4').show(200);
  $('#content1','#content2','#content3').hide('fast'); 
 
 });
});
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0 0;
  padding:0 0;
}
body {
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 margin-left: 0px;
 margin-right: 0px;
 font-family: sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
}
nav {
 width: 100%;
 height: 40px;
 position: fixed;
 background-color: silver;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: medium;
 padding-top: 30px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
}
#content1 {
 height: 500px;
 text-align: center;
 color: #000000;
 padding-top: 80px;
}
#content2 {
 height: 500px;
 text-align: center;
 color: #000000;
}
#content3 {
 height: 500px;
 text-align: center;
 color: #000000;
 }
#content4 {
 height: 500px;
 text-align: center;
 color: #000000;
}
a {
 color: #ffffff; 
 text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
 color:black;
}
a:hover {
 color: red;
}

img {
 padding: 30px;
 border-radius: 100%;
}
section{
 width: 1000px;
 padding-top: 30px;
 margin-left: 150px;
}
ul li{
  display:inline-block;
  list-style:none;
}
```

```html
<html>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

<script src="myscript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<nav>
 <ul>
   <li id="cats"><a href="#content1">Cats</a></li>
   <li id="food"><a href="#content2">Food</a></li>
    <li id="fashion"><a href="#content3">Fashion</a></li>
   <li id="animals"><a href="#content4">Animals</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
<body>
<section id="content1">
 <p><img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/400/cats/"></p>
   <p>Vivamus fringilla porttitor justo, ac varius neque tristique a. Duis iaculis augue a interdum pretium. Duis feugiat odio vel tortor tincidunt, in rhoncus lectus euismod. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Integer volutpat id orci et scelerisque. Nulla semper felis a risus egestas scelerisque. Ut tempus aliquam orci, pretium dapibus risus dictum at. Pellentesque consectetur eget est eu pulvinar. Nulla facilisi. Vivamus eu viverra turpis, et dapibus enim.</p></section>
<section id="content2">
 <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/400/food/">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut sodales elit sit amet nibh ultrices cursus. Fusce eget dolor fermentum, pulvinar mi vel, consequat lectus. Curabitur maximus nibh nunc, eu porta nibh commodo id. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Quisque eleifend, libero vitae venenatis vulputate, tortor magna cursus arcu, id viverra est ante ut est. Nulla placerat purus in fermentum lobortis. Integer sit amet dapibus orci.</p>
</section>

<section id="content3">
 <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/400/fashion/">
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut sodales elit sit amet nibh ultrices cursus. Fusce eget dolor fermentum, pulvinar mi vel, consequat lectus. Curabitur maximus nibh nunc, eu porta nibh commodo id. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Quisque eleifend, libero vitae venenatis vulputate, tortor magna cursus arcu, id viverra est ante ut est. Nulla placerat purus in fermentum lobortis. Integer sit amet dapibus orci.</p>
</section>

<section id="content4">
 <p><img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/400/animals/"></p>
   <p>Vivamus fringilla porttitor justo, ac varius neque tristique a. Duis iaculis augue a interdum pretium. Duis feugiat odio vel tortor tincidunt, in rhoncus lectus euismod. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Integer volutpat id orci et scelerisque. Nulla semper felis a risus egestas scelerisque. Ut tempus aliquam orci, pretium dapibus risus dictum at. Pellentesque consectetur eget est eu pulvinar. Nulla facilisi. Vivamus eu viverra turpis, et dapibus enim.</p>
</section>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You should use this instead: `$('#content2, #content3, #content4').hide('fast');`

Comment: @Vireonidae. See my answer with demo. I hope that it will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use comma-separated selectors within the same quotes—the way you are using it is equivalent to passing additional parameters, not selectors, to your jQuery object.

In other words, it should be: `$('#content1, #content3, #content4').hide('fast');` instead of `$('#content1','#content3','#content4').hide('fast');`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#cats').click(function(){
  $('#content1').show(200);
  $('#content2, #content3, #content4').hide('fast'); 
 
 });
 $('#food').click(function(){
  $('#content2').show(200);
  $('#content1','#content3','#content4').hide('fast'); 
 
 });
 $('#fashion').click(function(){
  $('#content3').show(200);
  $('#content1, #content2, #content4').hide('fast'); 
 
 });
 $('#animals').click(function(){
  $('#content4').show(200);
  $('#content1, #content2, #content3').hide('fast'); 
 
 });
});
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0 0;
  padding:0 0;
}
body {
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 margin-left: 0px;
 margin-right: 0px;
 font-family: sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
}
nav {
 width: 100%;
 height: 40px;
 position: fixed;
 background-color: silver;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: medium;
 padding-top: 30px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
}
#content1 {
 height: 500px;
 text-align: center;
 color: #000000;
 padding-top: 80px;
}
#content2 {
 height: 500px;
 text-align: center;
 color: #000000;
}
#content3 {
 height: 500px;
 text-align: center;
 color: #000000;
 }
#content4 {
 height: 500px;
 text-align: center;
 color: #000000;
}
a {
 color: #ffffff; 
 text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
 color:black;
}
a:hover {
 color: red;
}

img {
 padding: 30px;
 border-radius: 100%;
}
section{
 width: 1000px;
 padding-top: 30px;
 margin-left: 150px;
}
ul li{
  display:inline-block;
  list-style:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav>
 <ul>
   <li id="cats"><a href="#content1">Cats</a></li>
   <li id="food"><a href="#content2">Food</a></li>
    <li id="fashion"><a href="#content3">Fashion</a></li>
   <li id="animals"><a href="#content4">Animals</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
<body>
<section id="content1">
 <p><img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/400/cats/"></p>
   <p>Vivamus fringilla porttitor justo, ac varius neque tristique a. Duis iaculis augue a interdum pretium. Duis feugiat odio vel tortor tincidunt, in rhoncus lectus euismod. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Integer volutpat id orci et scelerisque. Nulla semper felis a risus egestas scelerisque. Ut tempus aliquam orci, pretium dapibus risus dictum at. Pellentesque consectetur eget est eu pulvinar. Nulla facilisi. Vivamus eu viverra turpis, et dapibus enim.</p></section>
<section id="content2">
 <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/400/food/">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut sodales elit sit amet nibh ultrices cursus. Fusce eget dolor fermentum, pulvinar mi vel, consequat lectus. Curabitur maximus nibh nunc, eu porta nibh commodo id. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Quisque eleifend, libero vitae venenatis vulputate, tortor magna cursus arcu, id viverra est ante ut est. Nulla placerat purus in fermentum lobortis. Integer sit amet dapibus orci.</p>
</section>

<section id="content3">
 <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/400/fashion/">
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut sodales elit sit amet nibh ultrices cursus. Fusce eget dolor fermentum, pulvinar mi vel, consequat lectus. Curabitur maximus nibh nunc, eu porta nibh commodo id. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Quisque eleifend, libero vitae venenatis vulputate, tortor magna cursus arcu, id viverra est ante ut est. Nulla placerat purus in fermentum lobortis. Integer sit amet dapibus orci.</p>
</section>

<section id="content4">
 <p><img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/400/animals/"></p>
   <p>Vivamus fringilla porttitor justo, ac varius neque tristique a. Duis iaculis augue a interdum pretium. Duis feugiat odio vel tortor tincidunt, in rhoncus lectus euismod. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Integer volutpat id orci et scelerisque. Nulla semper felis a risus egestas scelerisque. Ut tempus aliquam orci, pretium dapibus risus dictum at. Pellentesque consectetur eget est eu pulvinar. Nulla facilisi. Vivamus eu viverra turpis, et dapibus enim.</p>
</section>
```

**Optimization note**: Your jQuery code is actually overly redundant and can be simply reduced by using contextual cues:

In my improved example, I have given a common class to all your sections. When a `<li>` is clicked, it will hide all sections by default, but show the section whose ID is targeted by its children `<a>` element.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('nav ul li').click(function() {
    // Hide all sections
    $('section.content').hide();
    
    // Show only the relevant section
    var target = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
    $(target).show();
  });
});
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0 0;
  padding:0 0;
}
body {
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 margin-left: 0px;
 margin-right: 0px;
 font-family: sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
}
nav {
 width: 100%;
 height: 40px;
 position: fixed;
 background-color: silver;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: medium;
 padding-top: 30px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
}
#content1 {
 height: 500px;
 text-align: center;
 color: #000000;
 padding-top: 80px;
}
#content2 {
 height: 500px;
 text-align: center;
 color: #000000;
}
#content3 {
 height: 500px;
 text-align: center;
 color: #000000;
 }
#content4 {
 height: 500px;
 text-align: center;
 color: #000000;
}
a {
 color: #ffffff; 
 text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
 color:black;
}
a:hover {
 color: red;
}

img {
 padding: 30px;
 border-radius: 100%;
}
section{
 width: 1000px;
 padding-top: 30px;
 margin-left: 150px;
}
ul li{
  display:inline-block;
  list-style:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav>
 <ul>
   <li id="cats"><a href="#content1">Cats</a></li>
   <li id="food"><a href="#content2">Food</a></li>
    <li id="fashion"><a href="#content3">Fashion</a></li>
   <li id="animals"><a href="#content4">Animals</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
<body>
<section class="content" id="content1">
 <p><img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/400/cats/"></p>
   <p>Vivamus fringilla porttitor justo, ac varius neque tristique a. Duis iaculis augue a interdum pretium. Duis feugiat odio vel tortor tincidunt, in rhoncus lectus euismod. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Integer volutpat id orci et scelerisque. Nulla semper felis a risus egestas scelerisque. Ut tempus aliquam orci, pretium dapibus risus dictum at. Pellentesque consectetur eget est eu pulvinar. Nulla facilisi. Vivamus eu viverra turpis, et dapibus enim.</p></section>
<section class="content" id="content2">
 <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/400/food/">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut sodales elit sit amet nibh ultrices cursus. Fusce eget dolor fermentum, pulvinar mi vel, consequat lectus. Curabitur maximus nibh nunc, eu porta nibh commodo id. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Quisque eleifend, libero vitae venenatis vulputate, tortor magna cursus arcu, id viverra est ante ut est. Nulla placerat purus in fermentum lobortis. Integer sit amet dapibus orci.</p>
</section>

<section class="content" id="content3">
 <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/400/fashion/">
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut sodales elit sit amet nibh ultrices cursus. Fusce eget dolor fermentum, pulvinar mi vel, consequat lectus. Curabitur maximus nibh nunc, eu porta nibh commodo id. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Quisque eleifend, libero vitae venenatis vulputate, tortor magna cursus arcu, id viverra est ante ut est. Nulla placerat purus in fermentum lobortis. Integer sit amet dapibus orci.</p>
</section>

<section class="content" id="content4">
 <p><img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/400/animals/"></p>
   <p>Vivamus fringilla porttitor justo, ac varius neque tristique a. Duis iaculis augue a interdum pretium. Duis feugiat odio vel tortor tincidunt, in rhoncus lectus euismod. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Integer volutpat id orci et scelerisque. Nulla semper felis a risus egestas scelerisque. Ut tempus aliquam orci, pretium dapibus risus dictum at. Pellentesque consectetur eget est eu pulvinar. Nulla facilisi. Vivamus eu viverra turpis, et dapibus enim.</p>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many mistakes. I have optimized your codes. You can see it: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sherali/LkqTU/27037/)**

**1)** Your js is ugly.(also with mistakes). you should add `id` attribute to `<nav>` or `<ul>` tag. Then you can call each `a` through this id in click event.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#menu li a').click(function () {
        var href = $(this).attr("href");
        $(href)
            .show(200)
            .siblings().hide('fast');
        return false;

    });
});
```

**2)** Some html codes are placed in `<head>` tag. It should be in `<body>`.
Also, Your sections should be wrapped through block(div).

```
<nav id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li id="cats"><a href="#content1">Cats</a>
        </li>
        <li id="food"><a href="#content2">Food</a>
        </li>
        <li id="fashion"><a href="#content3">Fashion</a>
        </li>
        <li id="animals"><a href="#content4">Animals</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div class="contents">
    <section id="content1">
        ...
    </section>
    <section id="content2">
        ...
    </section>
    <section id="content3">
        ...
    </section>
    <section id="content4">
       ...
    </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys, I got it working and understood where I went wrong thanks to your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple selectors like CSS in one string to hide and show.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#cats').click(function(){
  $('#content1').show(200);
  $('#content2,#content3,#content4').hide('fast'); 
 
 });
 $('#food').click(function(){
  $('#content2').show(200);
  $('#content1,#content3,#content4').hide('fast'); 
 
 });
 $('#fashion').click(function(){
  $('#content3').show(200);
  $('#content1,#content2,#content4').hide('fast'); 
 
 });
 $('#animals').click(function(){
  $('#content4').show(200);
  $('#content1,#content2,#content3').hide('fast'); 
 
 });
});
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0 0;
  padding:0 0;
}
body {
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 margin-left: 0px;
 margin-right: 0px;
 font-family: sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
}
nav {
 width: 100%;
 height: 40px;
 position: fixed;
 background-color: silver;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: medium;
 padding-top: 30px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
}
#content1 {
 height: 500px;
 text-align: center;
 color: #000000;
 padding-top: 80px;
}
#content2 {
 height: 500px;
 text-align: center;
 color: #000000;
}
#content3 {
 height: 500px;
 text-align: center;
 color: #000000;
 }
#content4 {
 height: 500px;
 text-align: center;
 color: #000000;
}
a {
 color: #ffffff; 
 text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
 color:black;
}
a:hover {
 color: red;
}

img {
 padding: 30px;
 border-radius: 100%;
}
section{
 width: 1000px;
 padding-top: 30px;
 margin-left: 150px;
}
ul li{
  display:inline-block;
  list-style:none;
}
```

```html
<html>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

<script src="myscript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<nav>
 <ul>
   <li id="cats"><a href="#content1">Cats</a></li>
   <li id="food"><a href="#content2">Food</a></li>
    <li id="fashion"><a href="#content3">Fashion</a></li>
   <li id="animals"><a href="#content4">Animals</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
<body>
<section id="content1">
 <p><img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/400/cats/"></p>
   <p>Vivamus fringilla porttitor justo, ac varius neque tristique a. Duis iaculis augue a interdum pretium. Duis feugiat odio vel tortor tincidunt, in rhoncus lectus euismod. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Integer volutpat id orci et scelerisque. Nulla semper felis a risus egestas scelerisque. Ut tempus aliquam orci, pretium dapibus risus dictum at. Pellentesque consectetur eget est eu pulvinar. Nulla facilisi. Vivamus eu viverra turpis, et dapibus enim.</p></section>
<section id="content2">
 <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/400/food/">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut sodales elit sit amet nibh ultrices cursus. Fusce eget dolor fermentum, pulvinar mi vel, consequat lectus. Curabitur maximus nibh nunc, eu porta nibh commodo id. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Quisque eleifend, libero vitae venenatis vulputate, tortor magna cursus arcu, id viverra est ante ut est. Nulla placerat purus in fermentum lobortis. Integer sit amet dapibus orci.</p>
</section>

<section id="content3">
 <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/400/fashion/">
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut sodales elit sit amet nibh ultrices cursus. Fusce eget dolor fermentum, pulvinar mi vel, consequat lectus. Curabitur maximus nibh nunc, eu porta nibh commodo id. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Quisque eleifend, libero vitae venenatis vulputate, tortor magna cursus arcu, id viverra est ante ut est. Nulla placerat purus in fermentum lobortis. Integer sit amet dapibus orci.</p>
</section>

<section id="content4">
 <p><img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/400/animals/"></p>
   <p>Vivamus fringilla porttitor justo, ac varius neque tristique a. Duis iaculis augue a interdum pretium. Duis feugiat odio vel tortor tincidunt, in rhoncus lectus euismod. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Integer volutpat id orci et scelerisque. Nulla semper felis a risus egestas scelerisque. Ut tempus aliquam orci, pretium dapibus risus dictum at. Pellentesque consectetur eget est eu pulvinar. Nulla facilisi. Vivamus eu viverra turpis, et dapibus enim.</p>
</section>

</body>

</html>
```